# How can I convert a System.Drawing.font to a System.Windows.Media.Fonts or TypeFace?

Tags: c#, fonts

How can I convert a `System.Drawing.Font` to a `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` or `TypeFace`?

Or how can I generate an instance of `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` or `TypeFace` from an instance of `System.Drawing.Font`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you cant instantiate **Media.Fonts** , but I think you can get a **Media.FontFamily** this is how I achieved it.

```
using System.Drawing;
using Media = System.Windows.Media;

 Font font = new Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Comic Sans MS"), 10);
            //option 1
            Media.FontFamily mfont = new Media.FontFamily(font.Name);
            //option 2 does the same thing
            Media.FontFamilyConverter conv = new Media.FontFamilyConverter();
            Media.FontFamily mfont1 = conv.ConvertFromString(font.Name) as Media.FontFamily;
            //option 3
            Media.FontFamily mfont2 = Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.Where(x => x.Source == font.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What if the font is not installed on the system yet? Maybe we want to show a preview of the font before installation.

Comment: What if my font is from an embedded resource not installed on the system??

Answer (score 5):

I'm using below codes

```
private static Typeface NewTypeFaceFromFont(System.Drawing.Font f)
{
    Typeface typeface = null;

    FontFamily ff = new FontFamily(f.Name);


    if (typeface == null)
    {
        typeface = new Typeface(ff, (f.Style == System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal),
                         (f.Style == System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal),
                                    FontStretches.Normal);
    }
    if (typeface == null)
    {
        typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Arial"),
                                        FontStyles.Italic,
                                        FontWeights.Normal,
                                        FontStretches.Normal);            
    }
    return typeface;

}
```